# Twowayview with horizontal ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working on twowayview to get the horizontal listview. I tried importing library project into the eclipse. If I try to use the library by referring it, it works perfectly. But if I try use the jar twowayview.jar directly, it shows inflating error. Can't I just add jar file inside libs folder and use it? If can't, why?

Comment: Don't expect to explain everything here.Try something and share the code will help you out.